# How is this equation obtained? $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1} dx}{e^x-1}=\Pi(s-1)\zeta(s) $

Tags: integration, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

This equation:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} dx=\Pi(s-1)\zeta(s) $$
was used by Riemann in his famous paper from 1859.
Seemingly it follows from:
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx= \frac{\Pi(s-1)}{n^s}$$

a result achieved by repeated integration by parts. How does the first equation follows from the second?

Comment: To display exponents correctly, put it in braces (i.e. use "^{s - 1}" and the like).

Comment: Regarding your question - yes, the link is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{e^x - 1} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-nx}$.

Comment: Can you explain or share a link where it is explained how this can be derived?

Comment: What exactly? The [sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) or its termwise integration?

Comment: The termwise integration

Comment: Proof with details http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

A faster way to find the second equation would be to simply make the substitution $u = nx$ which leads to :

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \left( \frac{u}{n}\right)^{s-1} \frac{du}{n} = \frac{\Pi(s-1)}{n^s} \quad \quad (*)$$

You can also write :

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1}dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{s-1}\frac{1}{1 - e^{-x}}dx$$

And, you can write (geometric series) :

$$ \forall x >0, \ \frac{1}{1 - e^{-x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}$$

which leads to

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1}dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} dx $$

We can easily switch sum and integral, indeed :

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N,\ \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-(n+1)x} x^{s-1} \leqslant e^{-x} x^{s-1} = \varphi(x) $$

so we can apply the dominated convergence theorem with $\varphi \in L^1(\mathbb R_+^*)$. Using $(*)$ :

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Pi(s-1)}{(n+1)^s}  $$

Which is exactly :

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1}dx = \Pi(s-1)\zeta(s)  $$

Comment: Why is it valid to switch the sum and the integral?

Comment: @MisterSet What is the background you have? Are you aware of e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)?

Answer (score 1):

First we have that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nx}dx$$ Beliveing in uniform convergence we swap the sum and the integral to get $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-nx}dx$$ with a simple change of variable, we set $nx = t$ so $dt = ndx$, then $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-nx}dx = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^{s-1}e^{-t}dt = \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{-s}}_{\text{Def. of }\zeta(s)}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt}_{\text{Def. of }\Gamma(s)} = \zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$$ Just remember now the relation between the pi function and the Euler gamma function $$\Pi(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$$